# Bootstrap modal not working correctly with bootcards

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, z-index

[image: Bootcard modal disappears on click]Iam using this modal with bootstrap:

```
<div class="modal" id="contact-update-view">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Update contact</h4>                
                        </div>
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contact-create-name" class="col-sm-4  control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-create-name" name="contact-create-name" data-minlength="2" placeholder="Contact's Name" data-error="Name should atleast be 2 characters long" required />
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>    
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contact-create-phone" class="col-sm-4  control-label">Phone</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact-create-phone" name="contact-create-phone" placeholder="Phone Number" pattern="^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$"  data-error="Enter a valid phone number" required/>   
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="contact-create-email" class="col-sm-4  control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-create-email" name="contact-create-email" placeholder="Email" required data-error="The email is invalid"/>  
                                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Yep! Two exclamations and a question mark,arent you excited?">Add contact!</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                        </form>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I use the `bootcards-desktop.css` [from here](http://bootcards.org/index.html),I find that the backdrop is displayed above the `modal`.When I click on the modal it is dismissed immediately.

I open the modal with this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact-update-view">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
 </button>
```

I see this difference in the css:

```
.modal
        z-index:1050;
        position:fixed;

   .modal-backdrop:
       position:fixed;
       z-index:1040;
```

When I click on the modal,it disappears(as if there was a backdrop on top of the modal),how can I get the modal to work correctly with bootcards?

Comment: Just created a JSFiddle from your code. Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markleusink/62dL6wcn/embedded/result/), source [here](http://jsfiddle.net/markleusink/62dL6wcn/). I'm not seeing the same issue as you're having: the backdrop shows behind the dialog. Any change some other CSS is getting in the way?

Comment: @MarkLeusink Just managed to replicate the issue,[the code is on plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/icoOyW5gcxQVX0D0vsBE?p=preview)Is it because I depend on `bootstrap 3.3.1`?

Comment: Maybe [this conversation](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/issues/88) has something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Bootstrap 3.3.1 issues, nor a Bootcards issue. The problem is in the setup: the `bootcards-desktop.min.css` file (as well as the Android and iOS versions) is a concatenated version of Bootstrap (v3.2.0 at the moment) as well as the Bootcards CSS file. This is offered so you have one less HTTP request to make. In the `dist` folder of the Bootcards download, you'll also find versions of the CSS files without the built-in Bootstrap: they have a `-lite` suffix (and are a lot smaller...).

In your Plunkr, if I change the Bootstrap version to v3.3.1 AND change `bootcards-desktop.min.css` to `bootcards-desktop-lite.min.css` it all works again.

I'll release another version of Bootcards soon that will extend Bootstrap v3.3.1.